# Execute word/excel files from browser with php

Tags: php, excel, ms-word

I am creating a web application where user can use browser to execute `word/excel/pdf` files.

I have used `scandir()` to show list of files of a folder. Now when the user clicks the link, ie;name of the file(.doc, .xls, .pdf etc), the file should open with corresponding application.

The file should **not** open in browser. It should open normally with corresponding application.

How can I achieve this ?

I would be grateful if I could get any guidance on it.

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried sending the file to the web browser with appropriate filetytpe headers?

Comment: For the user to view any file stored on the server it needs to download it first. So you should be sending the files with the correct headers for each file type

Comment: @MarkBaker Actually I have not tried anything close to it because I really have no idea how to proceed with this.

Comment: Well then, try it and see what happens.... this is really web development 101

Comment: Could you please give me a link where I can see some examples on this? Thank you

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php